# Create new column with max value with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

From the following dataframe, I am trying to add a new column, with the condition that for every `id` check the maximium value. Then place the maximium value for each row of every `id` in the new column.

```
df

id  value
1   0
1   0
1   0
2   0
2   1
3   1
3   1
```

Expected result:

```
id  value new_column
1   0     0
1   0     0
1   0     0
2   0     1
2   1     1
3   1     1
3   1     1
```

I have tried:

```
df['new_column'] = df.groupby(['id'])['value'].idxmax()
```

Or:

```
df['new_column'] = df.groupby(['id'])['value'].max()
```

But neither of these give the desired result.

Comment: Try: `gb = df.groupby(['id'])['value'].reset_index()`, `df =df.merge(gb, on=['id'], how='left')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `transform` for this:

```
df['new_column'] = df.groupby(['id'])['value'].transform('max')
```

This more succinctly replicates the following:

```
df['new_column'] = df['id'].map(df.groupby(['id'])['value'].max())
```

Remember that the result of a `groupby` operation is a series with index set to grouper column(s).

Since indices are not aligned between your *original* dataframe and the `groupby` object, assignment will not happen automatically.